# in drupal 7 email not working with drupal_mail

Tags: jquery, validation, email, drupal-7

I want send mail in my page with jquery and php validation.

I have a text box to send mail while clicking submit button. drupal_mail is not working

Comment: make sure your mail settings are correct? like in site information , site email address , this is the address drupal uses as from mail

Comment: Please don't use the [tag:jquery-validate] tag when the question has nothing to do with this plugin.  Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have done the below settings

Under Configuration/Site Information under "Site Details" you MUST insert an email address from your domain, and then the email works.

Also there are many modules like SMTP Authentication support you can configure to send mails

[SMTP MODULE](http://drupal.org/project/smtp)